# Python: slicing a list into a list of lists using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, object-slicing

I have a simple list like this:

`mylist=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

which I want to slice creating a list of lists. The intended outcome is:

`sliced=[[0],[0,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3],...]`

---

1. First attempt:
   `sliced=[mylist[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(mylist), n)]`

   wrong result:
   `sliced=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]`

---

2. Second attempt: `sliced=[[mylist[l]] for l in range(0,10,1)]`

   wrong result:
   `sliced=[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]`

---

**How should I handle this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
>>> mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> sliced = [mylist[0:i] for i in range(1, len(mylist) + 1)]
>>> sliced
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Further reading: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)